# django south internal db functions in django 1.7

Tags: django, django-south, django-migrations

I have a project that was using the following internal db commands from `South` and was wondering if anyone knows how to do the same in `django 1.7`'s new migrations.

```
from south import db
...
db.delete_column(table,name)
...
db.add_column(table, name, field, keep_default=False)
....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new functionality is fully documented. In your case you want [`AddField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/migration-operations/#addfield) and [`RemoveField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/migration-operations/#removefield).

There is also a lower-level interface available via the [`SchemaEditor`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/schema-editor/) class.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I must've missed that.

Comment: any idea how i can commit a single operation?